# Hide Create and Export All button but show Import button in Odoo13 tree view

Tags: treeview, odoo, usergroups, odoo-13

By default Tree view in Odoo has Create, Import and Export All  button showing on top.
How do I hide them based on User groups?
Also I should be able to hide Create button but without hiding Import button.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the buttons like so:

```
<tree create="false" edit="false" delete="false" duplicate="false">
```

To do this per user group, create an inherited view and specify the group in the inherit view like so:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_model_name_tree_inherit">
    <field name="name">model.name.tree.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">model.name</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="module_name.tree_name" />
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('module_name.group_name'))]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree position="attributes">
            <attribute name="create">false</attribute>
            <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
            <attribute name="delete">false</attribute>
            <attribute name="duplicate">false</attribute>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Unfortunately the Create and Import buttons are both linked to the `create` attribute.

To disable the "Export" button, you will need to install a module as this is not supported on Odoo default. See [this module](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/web_disable_export_group/)

Comment: FYI, since Odoo Version 13.0, there is a way to disable import and export via the tree view XML: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/views.html#list

Answer (score 0):

You can check following link for solution of your problem. [web_disable_export_group](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/web_disable_export_group/)

If you want to hide **Export All** button on the top-up header and next to the create method for some views only then follow below step.

```
<tree string="Account"  export_xlsx="false" create="false">
```

But if you're using the **web_disable_export_group** and Did you uncheck the **Export Button** security group then for that user they are not able to see that **Export All** button for any views.[Reference](https://github.com/OCA/web/pull/1908)